# Cannot access Kubernetes pod

Tags: spring-boot, kubernetes, minikube, docker-desktop

I'm using Docker and Minikube on Windows for learning k8s, but I failed to deploy my first app.

I ran the following commands:

1. `kubectl run testapp --image=saphyra/testapp:latest --port=8080`
2. `kubectl expose deployment testapp --type=NodePort`
3. `minikube service testapp`

Using command  `minikube dashboard` I can see that the pod is created, and running, I can see the logs, and it says Tomcat started on port 8080 as expected.

So seems like everything is OK.

But how can I call the endpoint (from a browser) of the service I started?
The [tutorial](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-minikube) I followed (and many other YouTube tutorials) says now I have to be able to call the endpoints of the app.

What do I miss? How can I reach my app?

**Edit:**

Describe result

```
kubectl describe svc testapp >
Name:                     testapp
Namespace:                default
Labels:                   run=testapp
Annotations:              <none>
Selector:                 run=testapp
Type:                     NodePort
IP:                       10.110.10.61
Port:                     <unset>  8080/TCP
TargetPort:               8080/TCP
NodePort:                 <unset>  31612/TCP
Endpoints:                172.18.0.4:8080
Session Affinity:         None
External Traffic Policy:  Cluster
Events:                   <none>
```

kube proxy logs:

```
server_others.go:323] Unknown proxy mode "", assuming iptables proxy
node.go:135] Successfully retrieved node IP: 172.17.0.2
server_others.go:145] Using iptables Proxier.
server.go:571] Version: v1.17.3
conntrack.go:100] Set sysctl 'net/netfilter/nf_conntrack_max' to 524288
conntrack.go:52] Setting nf_conntrack_max to 524288
conntrack.go:127] sysfs is not writable: {Device:sysfs Path:/sys Type:sysfs Opts:[ro nosuid nodev noexec relatime] Freq:0 Pass:0} (mount options are [ro nosuid nodev noexec relatime])
conntrack.go:100] Set sysctl 'net/netfilter/nf_conntrack_tcp_timeout_established' to 86400
conntrack.go:100] Set sysctl 'net/netfilter/nf_conntrack_tcp_timeout_close_wait' to 3600
config.go:313] Starting service config controller
shared_informer.go:197] Waiting for caches to sync for service config
config.go:131] Starting endpoints config controller
shared_informer.go:197] Waiting for caches to sync for endpoints config
shared_informer.go:204] Caches are synced for service config 
shared_informer.go:204] Caches are synced for endpoints config
```

**EDIT 2**

`kubectl get svc testapp -o yaml` >

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  creationTimestamp: "2020-03-25T17:03:57Z"
  labels:
    run: testapp
  name: testapp
  namespace: default
  resourceVersion: "3454"
  selfLink: /api/v1/namespaces/default/services/testapp
  uid: 048d05df-eaad-4d4b-845f-d98b222fe101
spec:
  clusterIP: 10.110.10.61
  externalTrafficPolicy: Cluster
  ports:
  - nodePort: 31612
    port: 8080
    protocol: TCP
    targetPort: 8080
  selector:
    run: testapp
  sessionAffinity: None
  type: NodePort
status:
  loadBalancer: {}
```

`kubectl get pod testapp-c565bfccc-xht6j -o yaml` >

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  creationTimestamp: "2020-03-25T17:03:52Z"
  generateName: testapp-c565bfccc-
  labels:
    pod-template-hash: c565bfccc
    run: testapp
  name: testapp-c565bfccc-xht6j
  namespace: default
  ownerReferences:
  - apiVersion: apps/v1
    blockOwnerDeletion: true
    controller: true
    kind: ReplicaSet
    name: testapp-c565bfccc
    uid: 21e2c9ab-3771-482f-8849-71754aaf5ff6
  resourceVersion: "3491"
  selfLink: /api/v1/namespaces/default/pods/testapp-c565bfccc-xht6j
  uid: c4dfdcb6-d050-4c44-99d1-6881bc39f805
spec:
  containers:
  - image: saphyra/testapp:latest
    imagePullPolicy: Always
    name: testapp
    ports:
    - containerPort: 8080
      protocol: TCP
    resources: {}
    terminationMessagePath: /dev/termination-log
    terminationMessagePolicy: File
    volumeMounts:
    - mountPath: /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount
      name: default-token-689j9
      readOnly: true
  dnsPolicy: ClusterFirst
  enableServiceLinks: true
  nodeName: m01
  priority: 0
  restartPolicy: Always
  schedulerName: default-scheduler
  securityContext: {}
  serviceAccount: default
  serviceAccountName: default
  terminationGracePeriodSeconds: 30
  tolerations:
  - effect: NoExecute
    key: node.kubernetes.io/not-ready
    operator: Exists
    tolerationSeconds: 300
  - effect: NoExecute
    key: node.kubernetes.io/unreachable
    operator: Exists
    tolerationSeconds: 300
  volumes:
  - name: default-token-689j9
    secret:
      defaultMode: 420
      secretName: default-token-689j9
status:
  conditions:
  - lastProbeTime: null
    lastTransitionTime: "2020-03-25T17:03:52Z"
    status: "True"
    type: Initialized
  - lastProbeTime: null
    lastTransitionTime: "2020-03-25T17:04:12Z"
    status: "True"
    type: Ready
  - lastProbeTime: null
    lastTransitionTime: "2020-03-25T17:04:12Z"
    status: "True"
    type: ContainersReady
  - lastProbeTime: null
    lastTransitionTime: "2020-03-25T17:03:52Z"
    status: "True"
    type: PodScheduled
  containerStatuses:
  - containerID: docker://9a3ddc83df779bb4dc4b88718d82f7065d2dc647360fa200b4815ecc260a7ed4
    image: saphyra/testapp:latest
    imageID: docker-pullable://saphyra/testapp@sha256:b328a874297521f35c84a37cde160e23a39d6a12c7184dbe3c88ff0250b05df6
    lastState: {}
    name: testapp
    ready: true
    restartCount: 0
    started: true
    state:
      running:
        startedAt: "2020-03-25T17:04:11Z"
  hostIP: 172.17.0.2
  phase: Running
  podIP: 172.18.0.4
  podIPs:
  - ip: 172.18.0.4
  qosClass: BestEffort
  startTime: "2020-03-25T17:03:52Z"
```

Comment: minikube service testapp did not launch the browser?

Comment: It launched a tab in the browser, but ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

Comment: add output of kubectl describe svc testapp and logs of kube proxy pods in kube-system namespace

Comment: Requested data added @ArghyaSadhu

Answer (score 1):

Okay, finally I found:
minikube start selected 'docker' as driver, so the whole kubernetes was started in a docker container, and I guess docker container was not exposed to host.

When I set driver hyperv explicit, and minikube started its own vm, everything worked fine.

However it is still a question how can I expose minikube running in docker container.

Answer (score 0):

The Minikube VM is exposed to the host system via a host-only IP address, that can be obtained with the `$ minikube ip` command. Any services of type `NodePort` can be accessed over that IP address, on the `NodePort`.

From the information you provided, your service is listening to `NodePort:31612`. So, you can access your app from the browser by the following URL: `minikube-ip:NodePort`.

Let's say your minikube ip is `192.168.99.100` and the NodePort is `31612`, then the URL will be, 192.168.99.100:31612

Comment: `minikube ip` returned 172.17.0.2. Still no connection to 172.17.0.2:31612

Comment: make sure your service and application are functional, check whether `testapp.default.svc:8080` accessible inside the cluster. To do so, use `$ minikube ssh` and use `curl`.

Comment: `curl 172.18.0.4:8080` returned the expected response

Comment: add the yamls to the question, `kubectl get pod <pod-name> -o yaml` and `kubectl get svc <service-name> -o yaml`

Comment: Added to the question